# Internal redirect for POST in Play apps?

Tags: java, scala, model-view-controller, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play Framework 2.0.3 and would like to add a filter that will *internally* re-route certain requests (that is, *without* a 301/302) to a URL in the app that is determined *dynamically*. That is, the endpoint that I'll need to forward to depends on the request, so I don't know at compile time which controller/action it'll be, and can't just call them directly.

For example, if I get a request for `GET /foo?redirectTo=/bar`, how could I make Play internally route/process it as if it was actually a `POST /bar`?

This gist is my best guess so far, but it has some limitations: https://gist.github.com/brikis98/5582159

Comment: Is there anything that prevents you from adding two entries to your `routes` table, one for `GET /foo`, the other one for `POSt /bar`, with both of them pointing to the same Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here is a solution that seems to work:

```
object RedirectFilter extends Filter {

  def apply(next: RequestHeader => Result)(request: RequestHeader): Result = {

    getRedirectParams(request).flatMap { case (newRequest, body) =>
      route(newRequest).map { iteratee =>
        AsyncResult(Enumerator(body).run(iteratee))
      }
    } getOrElse {
      next(request)
    }
  }

  private def getRedirectParams(request: RequestHeader): Option[(RequestHeader, Array[Byte])] = {
    if (someCondition) {
      Some(toPostRequest(request), "Some new body data".getBytes("UTF-8"))      
    } else {
      None
    }
  }

  private def toPostRequest(originalRequest: RequestHeader): RequestHeader = {
    originalRequest.copy(
      uri = "/some/new/uri",
      path = "/some/new/uri",
      method = "POST"
    )
  }

  private def route(request: RequestHeader): Option[Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result]] = {
    Play.global.onRouteRequest(request).collect {
      case action: EssentialAction => Play.global.doFilter(action)(request)
    }
  }

}
```

Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/brikis98/5582159) for some other useful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the corresponding controller method.

Java version:

```
public static Result foo() {
    return bar();
}

public static Result bar() {
    return ok();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: A few things: (1) we have a filter chain that won't be executed the way it would be for a POST, (2) the GET parameters need to be turned into POST parameters, (3) the info in the request object will still have the GET URL, method, etc.

Comment: I updated the question with more explanation and a gist of my best guess so far.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to transform your Request from a GET request into a POST.
I'm not aware of any automatic way of doing that, but it should be fairly easy.

Could you explain a bit more why you need that ?

Julien.

Comment: Use case: the browser performs a POST that requires the user to be logged in. To log in, we 302 the user to a login page and pass it the original URL + params of the POST in the query string. The login page then 302's the user back to the original URL, and it as this point that we need to transform that 302 GET into a POST.

Comment: You could create a new request using something like: `Request(request, AnyContentAsFormUrlEncoded(request.queryString)).copy(method = "POST")` BUT I would rather handle that on the client size, since the body of you POST request may be too big to be serialized in a querystring.

Comment: Also it may create a security issue (CSRF)

Comment: I updated the question with more explanation and a gist of my best guess so far.